# getting .replace()'s 2nd parameter as function to return a JS Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code,

```
function itemFormatter(match, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, offset, string){
    var lineItem = {
        id: p3 ? p3 : p5,
        type: p1 ? p1 : p4,
        dualCheck: p2 ? true : false
    };
    console.log(lineItem);
    return lineItem;
}
var item = $(this).prop('id').replace(/(clItem[YNA]{1,})(DC)(\d{1,3})|(clItem[YNA]{1,})(\d{1,3})/g, itemFormatter);
console.log(item.id);
```

The purpose is to take a jQ object's id and return a js object created from the ID. However, the log inside itemFormatter() logs an actual object with data, and the log outside below the item variable returns `[object Object]` if you log just item and `undefined` if you log something like `item.id`.

How would I get lineItem to return properly, or with data as I am expecting?

---

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clItemCB', function(){
  function itemFormatter(match, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, offset, string){
    var lineItem = {
      id: p3 ? p3 : p5,
      type: p1 ? p1 : p4,
      dualCheck: p2 ? true : false
    };
    console.log(lineItem);
    return lineItem;
  }
  var item = $(this).prop('id').replace(/(clItem[YNA]{1,})(DC)(\d{1,3})|(clItem[YNA]{1,})(\d{1,3})/g, itemFormatter);
  console.log(item);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="clItemYDC253" class="clItemCB">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: What you're doing doesn't really make sense. The return value from a function callback passed to `.replace()` should be a **string**, not an object, because the behavior of `.replace()` is to use the returned value to replace the matched content (matched by the regex).

Comment: What you could do (if I understand the goal, and I'm not sure I do) would be to have the callback set the value of a variable declared *outside* the callback.

Comment: because you are storing a string into item, it is not a magical reference to `$(this)` and when you replace the string, it is not going to update the property of the element.

Comment: @Pointy I get what you're saying, I assumed because replace() could return a string it would return an object also. After re-skimming the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) I see it clearly states it will only return a string,  _"This method does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string."_ The goal was to turn the ID of an element into an object so it could be referenced easier later, there are a bunch of auto generated elements, it's a mess. Thank you though, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function itemFormatter(match, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, offset, string){
    var id = p3 ? p3 : p5,
      type = p1 ? p1 : p4,
      dualCheck = p2 ? true : false;
    // console.log(lineItem);
    return [id, type, dualCheck].join('-');
  }
  var item = $(this).prop('id').replace(/(clItem[YNA]{1,})(DC)(\d{1,3})|(clItem[YNA]{1,})(\d{1,3})/g, itemFormatter).split('-');
  console.log(item);
```

So this is what I came up with as a solution, Instead of trying to return an object from replace(), return a string that contains the reformatted information separated by hyphens, and then chain split() to the variable declaration. This breaks the string into an array a allowing the information to be accessed by index. Similar to the functionality I was trying to achieve through returning an object.

---

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clItemCB', function(){
      function itemFormatter(match, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, offset, string){
        var id = p3 ? p3 : p5,
          type = p1 ? p1 : p4,
          dualCheck = p2 ? true : false;
        // console.log(lineItem);
        return [id, type, dualCheck].join('-');
    }
    var item = $(this).prop('id').replace(/(clItem[YNA]{1,})(DC)(\d{1,3})|(clItem[YNA]{1,})(\d{1,3})/g, itemFormatter).split('-');
    console.log(item[0]+' I am the ID')
    console.log(item[1]+' I am the Type')
    console.log(item[2]+' I am for duplicate checking');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="clItemYDC253" class="clItemCB">Click Me!</button>
```